# Is $O(m \log n + n \log n )$ equal to $O((m+n) \log n )$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

I have a self study question and maybe very simple.

Can we conclude the following is true? Is it a property of asymptotic or log property?

$O(m \log n + n \log n )$ is equal to $O((m+n) \log n )$?

Comment: It's just distributing the $\log(n)$. $ax+bx = (a+b)x$

Comment: If $f(x)=g(x)$, then $O(f(x))=O(g(x))$. What's the big deal?

Comment: If it were the case that $O(m \log n + n \log n) \neq O((m + n) \log n)$ even though $m \log n + n \log n = (m + n) \log n$ then we would say that $O$ is not well-defined. You can be reasonably certain that any concept as widely used as Big-O notation will be well-defined. That said, a proof that $f(n) = g(n) \implies O(f(n)) = O(g(n))$ is pretty straightforward and might be a worthwhile exercise if you're having these kinds of doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the expression

$$ \mathcal{O}(m \log(n) + n \log(n) )  = \mathcal{O}((m+n) \log(n)) $$

this is just factoring the expression since

$$ m \log(n) + n \log(n) = (m+n)\log(n) $$

You'd probably be interested in the relationship between $m$ and $n$. Which one is larger?

Comment: Unless one is being held constant I don't think it really matters particularly for the equivalence between them. I'm just saying in the case you had some relationship it may reduce to something simpler. What the others said about $f(n) = g(n) \implies O(f(n) = O(g(n))$ is probably enough for the problem.